# SQlite updating column numbers in java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a scenario where number of columns is 2600. As mentioned in **SQLite** [limits](http://sqlite.org/limits.html) the maximum column supported is 2000.

Now I need to update the column numbers during run time, the definition,

> The maximum number of columns can be lowered at run-time using the `sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_COLUMN,size)` interface.

is not clear to me.

The code I'm using is,

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Where should I use the update column number code snippet and how? I couldnt get any direct examples. Please help.

EDIT:

> The default setting for SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN is 2000. 
>   You can change it at compile time to values as large as 32767.

How can i do this in sqlite jdbc??

Comment: Read carefully: "number of columns can be **lowered**", for increasing the number of columns you'd need to recompile SQLite.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So if in compile time i can increase the column numbers how should i do that?

Comment: I don't know how one would compile sqlite, but I assume it is a constant in one of the headers. However I'd first question the need to have 2600 columns in a single table.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The input file i got is like that, its an excel file where sheet name is table name and  each column data is a seperate column. In this case i have 2600 columns(till **CIG** in excel) as input.

Comment: I'd still wonder if the data is that flat, or can be organized in a different way (say a storage by row x column, or if there are repeating groups in the data, etc)

Comment: Maybe you can put the data in 2x 1300(+1) col table, while you don't need to retrieve all cols with a `select` all at once.