# SQLite JDBC column limit

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Following my previous question,

[SQlite updating column numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549425/sqlite-updating-column-numbers-in-java)

Is there any way to increase the column count in SQLite jar file (jdbc) ?? which is by default 2000. I have extracted SQLite jar file and looked into it for any default values but no use.

As mentioned by @PeterMmm in previous post i am opting to have two table splitting the columns.But is there any solution exists to increase it i will try it out.

EDIT : Am using SQLite 3.7.2 jar file

Comment: A database design that requires a table with more than 2000 columns sounds like a very big mistake.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes thatsy i opted to store in two different tables but still is there any way i can increase it? if i don mind about performance hit ..

Comment: The SQLite JDBC driver wraps the native library. So the limit is lifted in the same way as I mentioned in your previous question: increase the limit in the native code and recompile.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have two C files NativeDB.c and NestedDB.c files all other are JAVA files and i dont find any variables stating the maximum column count limit 2000. Could you please guide me to some site where i can find info about it.

Comment: The jar files contains the sqlite binaries. Look at https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc for the source of the JDBC driver. Looking at its makefile it downloads the native library from sqlite.org and the compiles it for inclusion.

Comment: Your problem is not the column limit but your database schema. You should ask a question about that.

Comment: @CL. Yeah..but i just need to know if i can increase the column limit as mentioned in SQLite site.

Comment: With a proper database schema, you would not need to increase the column limit.

Comment: @CL. am actually going to redesign my database schema.. But i need to know how to increase column limit..

Comment: @user3164187 Did you find any way to increase the column limit in jdbc driver?